# multiprocessing Listeners and Clients between python and pypy

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pypy

Is it possible to have a [Listener server process and a Client process](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.connection) where one of them uses a python interpreter and the other a [pypy](http://pypy.org/) interpreter?

Would `conn.send()` and `conn.recv()` interoperate well?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I tried it out to see:

```
import sys
from multiprocessing.connection import Listener, Client

address = ('localhost', 6000)

def client():
    conn = Client(address, authkey='secret password')
    print conn.recv_bytes()
    conn.close()

def server():
    listener = Listener(address, authkey='secret password')
    conn = listener.accept()
    print 'connection accepted from', listener.last_accepted
    conn.send_bytes('hello')
    conn.close()
    listener.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if sys.argv[1] == 'client':
        client()
    else:
        server()
```

Here are the results I got:

- CPython 2.7 + CPython 2.7: **working**
- PyPy 1.7 + PyPy 1.7: **working**
- CPython 2.7 + PyPy 1.7: **not working**
- CPython 2.7 + PyPy Nightly (pypy-c-jit-50911-94e9969b5f00-linux64): **working**

When using PyPy 1.7 (doesn't matter which is the server and which is the client), an error is reported with `IOError: bad message length`. This also mirrors [the report on the pypy-dev mailing list](http://www.mail-archive.com/pypy-dev@python.org/msg01607.html). However, this was recently fixed (it works in nightly build), so the next version (presumably 1.8) should have it fixed as well.

In general, this works because the multiprocessing module uses Python's [pickle](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html) module, which is stable and supported across multiple Python implementations, even PyPy.

Comment: It's awesome that you found that bug report!!